# Laravel Controller testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpspec

I am trying to test some laravel controllers but am not doing so well so far. I am meant to be using PHPSpec to do this. I have no idea where to start and I am meant to be testing the crud functionality of the controller. I understand how I might be able to do this, but really do not understand how I can translate this into a PHPSpec test.

```
   public function show($id)
   {
         $temp = $this->users->find($id);

         return Response::json($this->users->find($id));
   }
```

For example, how would I be able to test this method using PHPSpec?
Would it be as simple as assertions?
Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind showing the whole class you're trying to spec?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should use phpspec to test this. phpspec is primarily a tool for designing your object's API, and its interactions with other objects. For testing a controller you would probably want to do a more integrated test, and I think phpunit is more suited to this task.